# How to upmix stereo to 5.1 in VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player, 5.1

I'm trying to play non-5.1 (stereo) movies on VLC (Windows version) on a 5.1 system. Unfortunately, VLC by default doesn't upmix stereo to 5.1. I've tried experimenting with different settings and nothing seems to work. I admit, I'm a bit lost now. Does anyone know how to set it up?

Comment: Have you tried using the Speaker Fill option under Speaker Settings --> Enhancements?

Answer (score 0):

Use KODI to send the signal directly (pass-through) to your receiver. Make sure your audio device has the "[allow exclusive](http://kodi.wiki/view/windows_audio)" checkbox checked. Use the appropriate Surround program on your receiver to "upmix" to 5.1.

Other players and drivers may also support pass-through (e.g. [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm)), but I haven't tried recently.